# How do I use RtcPeerConnection to connect with other instances?

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, webrtc

I have followed the tutorials on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics as well as watch some of the videos but I am so confused. I was able to get 2 peerConnections working on a single page but I have no Idea how build on this to actually allow users on different machines/networks or what ever to actually connect.

From what I can see it involves using socket io and I have found plenty full frameworks and apps doing it but I am struggling to understand it.

Can any one point me to any tutorials that would help me to go from [this rtcPeerConnection](https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/tree/master/rtcpeerconnection) to communicating with other instances

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow 2 users establish p2p connection, one of the peer should send "description" (ip address, port, etc) to second peer. Second peer sets it as remote description using `setRemoteDescription` method of `RTCPeerConnection`. Second peer invokes `createAnswer` and sends its `localDescription` to first peer.

When both peers know about each other, connection can be established. I think that tutorial mentioned by you in first link is comprehensive.

To allow 2 peers exchange "descriptions" you can use any hand-written signalling server. For example client can poll web-server using http.

Comment: Thanks @Anton, I went back over the tutorial a few times, eventually got it